# filter data based on time (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data set

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 09:15:00 | 25 |
| 10:15:00 | 45 |
| 09:15:00 | 32 |
| 10:15:00 | 36 |
| 09:15:00 | 56 |
| 10:15:00 | 78 |

I would like to create a separate dataframe each based on the time

df0915:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 09:15:00 | 25 |
| 09:15:00 | 32 |
| 09:15:00 | 56 |

df1015:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10:15:00 | 45 |
| 10:15:00 | 36 |
| 10:15:00 | 78 |

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) with a list comprehension.

```
out = [d for _, d in df.groupby('Time')]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

[       Time  Value
 0  09:15:00     25
 2  09:15:00     32
 4  09:15:00     56,
        Time  Value
 1  10:15:00     45
 3  10:15:00     36
 5  10:15:00     78]
```

To access one of the dataframes, use `out[0]` or `out[1]`, ...**.**

Answer (score 0):

This will filter the dataframe:

```
df0915 = df[df['Time'] == '09:15:00']
df1015 = df[df['Time'] == '10:15:00']

print(df0915)
print(df1015)
```

**Output:**

```
       Time  Value
0  09:15:00     25
2  09:15:00     32
4  09:15:00     56
       Time  Value
1  10:15:00     45
3  10:15:00     36
5  10:15:00     78
```